Bread freshness in bread basket, Multi-Level Analysis in R; 2 time points
This is my first attempt with multi-level analysis.
My research question is;
How does the freshness of different types of bread (6 level) within a bread basket, change over two time points (ranging 4-8 days), dependent on the skill of the baker (4 level), and adjusting for intercorrelation among each basket, as one may have been made with higher quality ingredients than another?

Sample size = 300 bread baskets over 2 time points (600 total observations), 6 bread types per observation.

V1: id - IDs of each bread basket (with 6 correlated bread types per id)

V2: fresh - Freshness of bread 1 (Continuous, 0-100)

V3: skill - Skill of the baker (4 level ordered factor) (likert scale)

V4: time - Time since baked (Continuous, ranging 4-8 days)

V5: type - Kind of bread

V6-V8 Additional controlling variables (temp in cafe, oven condition, # baking assistants)


More simply, how does the skill of the baker (fixed) alter the effect of time on freshness of each type of bread within a bread basket, and also are those differences in effects (skill on freshness) statistically different across types of bread?
model_1 <- lmer(fresh ~ time * skill * type + V6 + V7 + V8 + (1|id), data = data)
This is in a way what I am hoping to show; That certain types of bread stay more fresh over time, with higher skill (freshness over time is significantly dependent on skill).

I appreciate any advice on how to approach this. This is a little more complex than what I’m used to, so any pointers on steps to take, or reference to similar analysis, would be really appreciated. Thanks!


Aren't these artificial data?
